# Apple Magic Trackpad 3-Finger drop lag

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, lag, magic-trackpad

After [enabling](http://www.cultofmac.com/134931/use-three-fingers-and-revolutionize-using-your-mac-os-x-tips/) three-finger dragging for my Trackpad, I notice that it drags well, but when I release there is about 1-2 seconds of lag before it actually drops. I understand this is supposed to be a feature so when you run out of space to drag, you have time to move your hand. But, for those of us powerusers, who move really fast, this is a BUG, not a feature. There should be some way to turn it off!

For some perspective, I personally own a [Fingerworks trackpad](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00013MVT4) as well (the company Apple bought to make the Trackpad) and it does not suffer this problem. Drops are instantaneous no matter what program I am in. This is hugely frustrating for me, because I thought I was upgrading here and Apple's version does not perform as well as the Fingerworks model (which I purchased in 2004)

I actually [made a short video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U479CzFHLAE) illustrating the problem, and why it is so frustrating for anyone who uses the pad as an artistic tool. Anyone here face this problem? If not, how would you recommend that I address Apple directly about this?

PS - Already looked at [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16052/apple-magic-trackpad-issue-occasionally-it-interprets-one-finger-click-as-two-f) and the conclusion does not help me. I do not have one-finger drag enabled.

PPS - I understand that for most people this is not an issue because they use the 'click' feature of the Trackpad. However, after years of using Fingerworks and not having to click ever, I find that it slows me down.

Comment: It's a good question because it's entirely possible that this delay option exists _somewhere_ I just don't think anyone has *found it* yet

Comment: I am convinced it is buried in there somewhere, though not being a seasoned Objective-C programmer I am definitely not equipped to dive that deep. I also posted this question in Apple's Discussion site - hopefully someone with serious coding chops will chime in.

Answer (score 5):

One option (my current solution) is to add a quick tap-in-place at the end of the drag. This signals that the drag is over and eliminates the need for the short delay. Still not ideal, but better than nothing.

Comment: I realize this is a very old question (haha), but I'm glad you posted this workaround. I get why the delay's there, but a modifier key would probably be a better way to keep holding the object when resetting your hand on the trackpad. As a note; at least in Logic Pro, I've noticed you can just tap one finger (leaving the other two in place) to release most drag objects (e.g., automation breakpoints). If find it a little easier and more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

This is free utility, that release the mouse down immediately.
https://nodragreleasedelay.pravdomil.com

Comment: Thanks for the link. Doesn't seem to work for me but it might just be a Yosemite issue

Answer (score 0):

Provided its vast customizing abilities, you should be able to solve your problem with [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/).

Comment: I have tried both BetterTouchTool and [MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com/) While both provide a wealth of options for customizing/assigning gestures, neither offers an override for the default behavior of a 3-finger drag. :(